# Opensource web application to organise calenders

Tags: web-apps, knowledge-organization

At the institute where I am working we have several rooms that are being used e.g. for teaching and exams. Currently, we don't have a system in place to manage the booking of these rooms.

I am searching for a free and open source system for calendar management that I can install on a simple webspace with a MySQL database. The system must allow to set up several calendars as well as to share them publicly and allow users to apply changes. Support of WebDAV would be a plus.

I suppose [Nextcloud with its calendar plugin](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/calendar) would do the job but maybe running a Nextcloud instance is a bit overengineered for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend an opensource version of [BookedScheduler](https://github.com/effgarces/BookedScheduler/).

It is a web app that can be used for booking resourses like rooms, equipment etc.

You can try out a demo of the SaaS version [here](https://demo.bookedscheduler.com/Web/).